# HTTP request based connection vs application lifetime connection when using CrmServiceClient

Tags: .net, web-applications, asp.net-mvc-5, dynamics-crm-365

I'm working on ASP.NET MVC5 application and i'm not very familiar with `CrmServiceClient` so i i need help in deciding which approach would be better for my application.

Little explanation how application is conceived, Application will have users/agents that that will operate in application. Biggest problem is how should this look? Should i make for every user/agent his own instance/connection of `CrmServiceClient`(every user would be "systemuser" in CRM and would provide his credentials) or i should make one instance/connection of `CrmServiceClient`(as admin from CRM) and do all the operation.

**HTTP request based connection:** 
With this approach am not sure how will `CrmServiceClient` act if for every 
request that every user made i create new instance(open new connection) and when request is over i `Dispose()` it? Will i get new instance for every user or i will get same instance for user that already made connection in some previous request?

**Application lifetime connection:** 
With this approach i would create an instance/connection of `CrmServiceClient` when application start and keep it open for whole application lifetime so every every user that make request would use same instance. Could this be a big performance issue due it's only one instance/connection that's open to CRM?
How will that instance/connection act after some time? will it close automatically or stay open? (for simplicity let's say that application needs to run for days, months, years etc...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about `CrmServiceClient` however I know that `HttpClient` should be kept open for the Application Lifetime (i.e. should not be used in a `using` structure nor disposed after each request).

Could you check what structure `CrmServiceClient` uses under the hood?

Comment: `CrmServiceClient` use `OrganizationServiceProxy`, did you mean that or something else? Anyway i chose **Application lifetime connection** and i implemented custom connectionpool of `CrmServiceClient`.